# Error with Sequelize v4

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I have just coding the todolist api project on NodeJS & Express. I follow some instruction using Sequelize to interact with DB: SQLite. But I encounter with Sequelize to create class method as below:

**user.js**

```
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
var _ = require('underscore');

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
var User = sequelize.define('user', {
    email: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true,
        validate: {
            isEmail: true
        }
    },
    salt: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    password_hash: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    password: {
        type: DataTypes.VIRTUAL,
        allowNull: false,
        validate: {
            len: [6, 100]
        },
        set: function (value) {
            var salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);
            var hashedPassword = bcrypt.hashSync(value, salt);

            this.setDataValue('password', value);
            this.setDataValue('salt', salt);
            this.setDataValue('password_hash', hashedPassword);
        }
    }
}, {
    hooks: {
        beforeValidate: (user, options) => {
            if (typeof user.email === 'string') {
                user.email = user.email.toLowerCase();
            }
        }
    }
});
return User;

// Class methods
User.prototype.toPublicJSON = function() {
    var json = this.toJSON();
    return _.pick(json, 'id', 'email', 'createdAt', 'updatedAt');
};

User.authenticate = (body) => {
    return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
        if (typeof body.email !== 'string' || typeof body.password !== 'string') {
            return reject();
        }

        user.findOne({
            where: {
                email: body.email
            }
        }).then((user) => {
            if (!user || !bcrypt.compareSync(body.password, user.get('password_hash'))) {
                return reject();
            }

            resolve(user);
        }, (e) => {
            reject();
        })
    });
};
}
```

**db.js**

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');

var sequelize = new Sequelize(undefined, undefined, undefined, {
  'dialect': 'sqlite',
  'storage': __dirname + '/data/dev-todo-api.sqlite'
});

db = {};

db.todo = sequelize.import(__dirname + '/models/todo.js');
db.user = sequelize.import(__dirname + '/models/user.js');
db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

**user.js**

```
app.post('/users/login', (req, res) => {
  var body = _.pick(req.body, 'email', 'password');

  db.user.authenticate(body).then((user) => {
    res.json(user.toPublicJSON());
  }, () => {
    res.status(401).send();
  });
})
```

**Error: db.user.authenticate is not function.**

I think I can use function authenticate after user.js return variable User. Please advise me how to resolve this problem. Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with `sequelize`. Rather you are defining the methods after return, so the code that is responsible for creating the methods is never reached.

```
return User;

// Class methods
User.prototype.toPublicJSON = function() {
    var json = this.toJSON();
    return _.pick(json, 'id', 'email', 'createdAt', 'updatedAt');
};

User.authenticate = (body) => {
```

You should move the `return User` statement at the end of your arrow function and your code should work.

Comment: Dear shawon191, I change my code as you suggest but it always return status(401) (I give right data). I detect I make a mistake as below:
user.findOne({}) ==> User.findOne({}). Everything is ok now. Many thanks for your support.